# HTML Image Slider not on Heroku

Tags: php, html, css, heroku

my image slider isn't working on heroku but when I run the code on localhost it works fine

heroku=> https://phpstore-website.herokuapp.com/

github repo=> https://github.com/verma-tanishq/phpstore

```html
<section class="section-slide">
    <div class="wrap-slick1">
        <div class="slick1">
            <div class="item-slick1" style="background-image: url(images/slide-01.jpg);">
                <div class="container h-full">
                    <div class="flex-col-l-m h-full p-t-100 p-b-30 respon5">
                        <div class="layer-slick1 animated visible-false" data-appear="fadeInDown" data-delay="0">
                            <span class="ltext-101 cl2 respon2">
                                Women Collection 2018
                            </span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="layer-slick1 animated visible-false" data-appear="fadeInUp" data-delay="800">
                            <h2 class="ltext-201 cl2 p-t-19 p-b-43 respon1">
                                NEW SEASON
                            </h2>
                        </div>

                        <div class="layer-slick1 animated visible-false" data-appear="zoomIn" data-delay="1600">
                            <a href="product.php"
                                class="flex-c-m stext-101 cl0 size-101 bg1 bor1 hov-btn1 p-lr-15 trans-04">
                                Shop Now
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item-slick1" style="background-image: url(images/slide-03.jpg);">
                <div class="container h-full">
                    <div class="flex-col-l-m h-full p-t-100 p-b-30 respon5">
                        <div class="layer-slick1 animated visible-false" data-appear="rotateInDownLeft" data-delay="0">
                            <span class="ltext-101 cl2 respon2">
                                Men Collection 2018
                            </span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="layer-slick1 animated visible-false" data-appear="rotateInUpRight" data-delay="800">
                            <h2 class="ltext-201 cl2 p-t-19 p-b-43 respon1">
                                New arrivals
                            </h2>
                        </div>

                        <div class="layer-slick1 animated visible-false" data-appear="rotateIn" data-delay="1600">
                            <a href="product.php"
                                class="flex-c-m stext-101 cl0 size-101 bg1 bor1 hov-btn1 p-lr-15 trans-04">
                                Shop Now
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

[When running on localhost, works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwSwr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple css files are not loaded because of 403 Forbidden Access error, that is why styles are not applied. For e.g. [This file](https://phpstore-website.herokuapp.com/vendor/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.css) is one of them which is forbidden. You can check that in the network tab in dev tools. You need to configure your app so that these files are also public.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like the version of css styling of the service provider might be outdated
https://kosumi.000webhostapp.com/phpstore-master/
i have tried in the web host i use for my own site and it worked perfectly, depending of situation you should change the service you use for web host...but i dont reccomend 000webhost for bigger sites, just for testing ones